# Override function in wordpress child theme inc subfolder

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I have read all the documentation about this but i cant handle it!
Im using third party wordpress theme, childtheme as well. I want to make some modifications in the child theme in one file which is based in inc/widgets folder, but i cant handle with the overriding. What information i must provide you, to improve my question and get help? Thanks!

Comment: first question is: do you need to modify the widget code? Or only looking for a way to modify the child theme?

Comment: I want to modify one exact div in the widget code! I already know that if i just copy the edited file with the same folder structure in my child theme - its not working.

Comment: take a look at [the answers here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/229772/how-can-i-modify-the-wordpress-default-widget-output) then, it gives you different solutions that should help you understand. You can either copy the widget file and include it, or extend its class, in functions.php. You also need to declare the new widget as said in the answers